Finding a counterexample of a function such that the $\omega$-th application differs from the $\omega+1$-th application
Let $A$ be a set and $f\colon A \to A$. Define the sequence $A_0=A, A_{n+1}=f_*(A_n)$ i.e. $A_n$ is the image through $f$ composed with itself $n$ times.
Now define $B= \bigcap_{n \geq 0} A_n$
Prove $f_*(B) \subseteq B$ and prove or give a counterexample for the reversed inclusion.
My attempt:
It is a common fact about functions that $f_*( \bigcap S) \subseteq \bigcap_{X \in S} f_*(X)$ with the reverse inclusion being equivalent to the function being injective (if we universally quantify over non-empty $S$)
Since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \colon A_n \supseteq A_{n+1}$, we have that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \colon B = \bigcap_{m \geq n} A_m$
Now $f_*(B) = f_*( \bigcap_{n \geq 0} A_n) \subseteq \bigcap_{n \geq 0}f_*(A_n)=  \bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_n=B$
I couldn’t find a counterexample for the reversed inclusion. It is clear that we have to search for non injective functions.
I don’t know if my argument counts as valid for the reversed inclusion:
For any ordinal $\alpha$ extend the sequence as follows $A_0=A, A_{\alpha+1}=f_*(A_\alpha) \text{and for limit ordinals: } A_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\beta \in \alpha}A_\beta$
So we basically have to find an example where the inclusion $A_\omega \supset A_{\omega+1}$ is not an equality.
Is that possible since any non increasing sequence of ordinals must eventually become constant?

Why do you used ordinals ? I don’t get it.

Ordinals were for the seond question. If you look closely you can see that I answered the first part in my question. I did the same proof for the first part as you have posted it bellow

Oh yes I skipped a line sorry

@Shthephathord23 I suggest to choose a better title that describes the question more than the current one.

Are $f$ and $f_\ast$ the same thing?

@MartinBrandenburg do you have a better idea for the title? I am open to new suggestions.

@Taladris if we have a function $f\colon A \to B$ and $C \subseteq A$, then $f_(C)={ y \in B \mid \exists x \in C \colon y=f(x) }$ is the direct image of $C$ through $f$ and if $D \subseteq B$ then $f^(D)={x \in A \mid \exists y \in D \colon f(x)=y }$ is the inverse image of $D$

Your new title is fine. I just fixed the typo. Nice question by the way.

@Shthephathord23: ha thanks. I usually see these sets denoted by $f(C)$ and $f^{-1}*(D)$ respectively, not with the push forward/pull back notations.

Note that $A_n$ consists of those $a \in A$ that terminate a chain of length $n$, meaning
$$(\exists x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in A) \quad x_1 \xrightarrow{f} x_2 \xrightarrow{f} \ldots \xrightarrow{f} x_n \xrightarrow{f} a.$$
Hence:

$B$ consists of those $a \in A$ that terminate arbitrary long chains.
$f_*(B)$ consists of those $a \in A$, for which there is some $b \in A$ with $b \xrightarrow{f} a$ and $b$ terminates arbitrary long chains .

If you think for a moment, the former does not imply the latter. In fact, we can use this description to forge a counterexample:

Here $a_1$ terminates arbitrary long chains but is not mapped to by an element with the same property, hence $a_1 \in B \setminus f_*(B)$ and so $f_*(B) \subsetneq B$. In fact, $B = \{ a_n : n \geqslant 1 \}$ and $f_*(B) = \{ a_n : n \geqslant 2 \}$.

The image is a perfect explanation of what is happening here, +1. Since your set is countable, we will be able to find an example on $\mathbb{N}$. The answer by Alex shows that we may simplify to $a_n=a_1$.

@MartinBrandenburg Rather, $a_n=a_2$ for $n\geq 2$.

Here is a formal version of the other answers.
Let $A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : x \leq y\} \sqcup \{a,b\}$. Define $f(x,y) := (x-1,y)$ if $x \geq 1$, $f(0,y) := a$, $f(a) := b$, and $f(b) := b$. Then $B=\{a,b\}$, and $f$ maps this to $\{b\}$.

Not quite right, I think, since $(0,0)$ is not in the image of $f$.

@AlexKruckman Yes, thanks. for pointing this out. It is fixed.

Let $T$ be a tree consisting of a root $r$ and, for each $n\in\omega$, a path of length $n$ extending from the root. Let $A=T\cup\{*\}$, and define $f\colon A\to A$ by $f(r)=f(*)=*$ and $f(v)=$ the predecessor of $v$ for all other $v$.
Then $B=\{r,*\}$, but $f(B)=\{*\}$.
